# Sky like iron and earth like bronze

Tags: leviticus

In Leviticus 26:19 (NASB)

> I will also (break down your pride of power; and **I will make your sky like iron and your earth like bronze**.

What's the meaning of this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means no rain from heaven and therefore nothing will grow on earth. Similar threat is found in
Deuteronomy 28:23-24

> 23 The sky over your head will be bronze, the ground beneath you iron. 24 The Lord will turn the rain of your country into dust and powder; it will come down from the skies until you are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

It means more difficult than that material. Iron Sword. Bronze Shovel.

Imagine being a farmer.

It means bronze spear, iron sword.

pruning hooks & plowshares

It means a foreign army (if).

It means Yellowstone fallout (basaltic powder 'soil')
It means the dust bowl (dust).

It means Aluminum Phosphor Bronze. America started Aluminum mining (Alcoa), and our water pipes contain phosphorous.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you clarify your answer? We're typically looking for a little more detail. Please be sure to take the site [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and thanks for contributing!